# Tables/Functions Not getting created in Postgresql using DBeaver

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, dbeaver

I using DBeaver to connect to my postgresql and i am running commands to create table and to create functions and even tried to alter table. The SQL is running fine but no tables/functions are getting created.. It very weird.

Also using the same tool and i am able to create table and do other stuffs in other env but only in an particular env its giving me this issue. The issue is query is running fine but nothing is happening. Can you please help me in this?

Thanks.

Comment: Guess - Transactional DDL? `CREATE TABLE  tab(...); COMMIT;`

Comment: Thanks a lot,,,it worked for me...